# MyBatis+Spring+Jersey with Oracle Seems to reuses SQL sessions

Tags: spring, mybatis, oracle12c, spring-mybatis

I'm creating a rest service using MyBatis 3.3.1, Spring 4.3, Jersey 2.22 and Oracle 12c.  My transactions are being managed by Spring using the DataSourceTransactionManager and the @Transaction annotaion. I am also using a MyBatis pooled data source as my javax.sql.DataSource. What I don't understand if why database sessions are being reused.

In my application, I am setting an oracle client identifier: DBMS_SESSION.SET_IDENTIFIER("my id"). With the debug logging statements, I can see MyBatis creating new sessions for each of the MyBatis sql operations. I also have debug to print out the database session identifier from DBMS_SESSION.UNIQUE_SESSION_ID.

What I don't understand is that if I access my rest endpoint multiple times, the unique session id is the same and the identifier from my last access is still set.

Shouldn't a new oracle session be used every time MyBatis gets a new SQLSession? Why is the oracle session always the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session in Oracle is bound to a connection.
You are using connection pooling so after one rest request is finished the connection is returned to the connection pool. Session is not terminated in this case.

You probably want to clear identifier on returning connection to pool and setting it on retrieving connection from the pool. The exact way to do that depends on the connection pool you are using. For built-in mybatis connection pool see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25442075/connection-pool-call-a-procedure-each-time-an-operation-is-made).

Comment: Hi Roman, Thank you for your comment. I tried doing something similar with Transactions, having the correct session variables set when a transaction starts and removed when a transaction ends. However, based on the debug, it seems like MyBatis calls create session multiple times within the @Transactional method. I can see the sessions being created and then added to the current transaction. Is it expected that multiple sessions would make up a transaction? When the transaction commits, does it commit on all the sessions?

Comment: It depends on the configuration of spring and mybatis. Usually one session is created for the duration of the transaction. The central method which implements this logic is `org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils.getSqlSession`.

Comment: I think your problem is that you have two datasources. One is configured in mybatis and the other managed by spring. Spring does not know about mybatis pooled datasource. How is you `SqlSessionFactory` is configured?